# Animation what does * (asterisk) mean in height value

Tags: angular, animation

I peep into ng2-dropdown

and I can see (ng2-dropdown-menu.ts)

among other things

```
transition('hidden => visible', [
                animate(150, keyframes([
                    style({opacity: 0, offset: 0, height: '0', width: '0'}),
                    style({opacity: 1, offset: 1, height: '*', width: '*'}),
                ]))
            ])
```

what does * (asterisk) mean in height value ?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/animations/style#auto-styles-using-

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk means that the height and width will be computed dynamically at runtime.